# tapping on phone link not openning the dial pad

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

Please help. Phone link not opening the dial pad. Please see the html below. I'm using JQuery Mobile with html5 and asp.net mvc 5. I used the tel protocol in the anchor tag but when I taps on the link, it is not opening the dial pad. It opens skype when i test it on emulator but not on actual device. I'm using Samsung Galaxy s5.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device width, initial-scale=1" />
        @*<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=yes">*@

        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.intellisense.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.js"></script>
        <title>Attorney Contacts</title>
        <link href="~/Content/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="~/Content/Contact.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            Mobile Site
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="tel://1-555-555-5555">+1 (555) 555-5555</a>
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            footer content
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

On mobile devices, there are protocol handlers to launch the phone. Depending on the security, some will dial it, or others will bring on the phone application with the number already there.

I also think that the syntax should be as follows

```
<a href="tel:+15555555555">+1 (555) 555-5555</a>
```

Hope this helps!

Regards.

Shreerang

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please let me know about those protocol handlers to launch the phone. I tried with different  Also what security settings do I need to set. mail to link is also not opening the email application on the phone. I have the link: <a href="mailto:yasnake@gmail.com">yasnake@gmail.com</a>. When I tap on both the phone and email link, it goes to error page saying "Webpage not available" I tried <a href="tel:+15555555555">+1 (555) 555-5555</a> for the phone but still getting the error message. Please help